# show if $A = B \oplus C$ then $B\cap C = \{0\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

show if $A = B \oplus C$ then $B \cap C = \{0\}$.

attempt:

suppose, $ a \in A = B \oplus C$, then by definition we can write $ a = b + c$ for unique $b$ and $c$. Now I am trying to take a general $z \in B \cap C$ and show that it must be $0$, but I am having troubles

Answer (score 2):

It can be written as $z=0+z$ as well as $z+0$. By uniqueness, $z=0$.

Comment: but this is a general z, you don't know that $z$ is unique, that's only for $ z \in $ the direct sum of B and C?>

Comment: @algebrahelp he's not saying $z$ is unique. He's saying because $z$ is in both $B$ and $C$, you can write $z=0+z$ and $z=z+0$ and these are both valid ways to write it as a sum of elements from $B$ and $C$. However, this way of writing it should be unique so $0+z=z+0$ means $z$ must itself be $0$.

Comment: why should this way of writing be unique?

Comment: This is in the definition of a direct sum. The left term is in $B$ and the right term, in $C$.

Answer (score 0):

If you write $z = b +c$ uniquely with $b \in B, \; c \in C$ then observe that $c = 0$ since $z \in B$ and $b = 0$ since $z \in C$.

Answer (score 0):

Take that $a=b+c$ that you have, where $a$ determines $b$ and $c$ uniquely. Let $z\in B\cap C$ be non-zero. What can you say about the expression
$$
(b+z)+(c-z)
$$
and how is that a contradiction?